# How to convert pixel co-ordinates for use with MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE

Tags: delphi, mouseevent, sendinput

I am moving the mouse pointer with SendInput.  Using the conversion of co-ordinates as per MSDN works fine sending absolute values.  Relative values is a different matter. Trial and error would indicate that a factor of about 0.625 gives the correct result for both directions.
How do I calculate the factor one must use for relative co-ordinate conversion?
The code I am using looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.BtAbsoluteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Inp: TInput;
  xp,yp: integer; //pixel co-ordinates
  xn,yn: integer; //normalised co-ordinates
begin
  xp := 500;
  yp := 200;
  {calculate normalised co-ordinates}
  xn := round(xp*65536/Screen.Width);
  yn := round(yp*65536/Screen.Height);
  {move mouse pointer}
  Inp.IType := INPUT_MOUSE;
  Inp.mi.dx := xn;
  Inp.mi.dy := yn;
  Inp.mi.mouseData := 0;
  Inp.mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
  Inp.mi.time := 0;
  Inp.mi.dwExtraInfo := 0;
  SendInput(1, Inp, SizeOf(Inp));
end;

procedure TForm1.BtRelativClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Inp: TInput;
  xp,yp: integer; //pixel co-ordinates
  xn,yn: integer; //normalised co-ordinates
begin
  xp := 500; //with no correction cursor moves to 800  >>  0.625
  yp := 200; //with no correction cursor moves to 318  >>  0.625
  {calculate normalised co-ordinates}
  xn := round(xp*0.625);
  yn := round(yp*0.625);
  {move mouse pointer}
  Inp.IType := INPUT_MOUSE;
  Inp.mi.dx := xn;
  Inp.mi.dy := yn;
  Inp.mi.mouseData := 0;
  Inp.mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
  Inp.mi.time := 0;
  Inp.mi.dwExtraInfo := 0;
  SendInput(1, Inp, SizeOf(Inp));
end;
```

I am using Delphi 10 running on Win10

Comment: Do not calculate normalized coordinates without `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx (see Remarks section)

Comment: @Kami I did not find a specific reference in the Microsoft documentation.  However it made me do some goggling on "Mickey" and this made it clear to me that one would have to know detailed specifications of the mouse.  I will stick to MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE.  Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use SendInput function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) instead since it supersede the Mouse_Event function.  From what I can gather from its documentation it does not deal with `mickeys` but with pixels even when dealing with relative movements. And probably the best feature is that it allows you to insert multiple input commands at once.

Comment: @SilverWarior If you look at my code you see that I am using SendInput.  And no,  relative mouse movement is not using pixels.